# PHP Calendar - merge cells for events that last longer than a day

Tags: php, calendar

I know I might get a bad rep for this or a closed topic, but I really have no clue about what I'm about to ask. I have [this PHP code](http://pastebin.com/Adc106EP) which generates a simple calendar. I will add events in it and display them with a proper highlighting. What I fail to accomplish is to merge cells for an event that lasts more than a day. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging cells, would it not make sense to colour code the cells together. You cant merge cells if they span over a week anyway, as the month is split into weeks (sunday to saturday). I would suggest colour coding (a div or a span) inside the cell with the event in it. You can then have the title of the event (or the first few words, and the rest of the details in a popup on mouseover) inside the span.

Comment: This way you can have multiple events in the day too.